# Negative Mass Square

Tags: mass, standard-model, neutrinos

I'm reading a book about neutrino physics (from 1997).
In the chapter about neutrino mass they list results of certain experiments. All of them get a negative value for $m(\nu_e)^2$ but a positive one for $m(\nu_e)$.

Does one has to take the absolut square for calculating the mass?

Afaik the mass as physical property has to be real, right? I know that the mass eigenstates are different from the flavour eigenstates, but are the masseigenvalues of the mass eigenstates real and positive?

EDIT:

Link to the book:

http://www.amazon.de/Neutrinophysik-Teubner-Studienb%C3%BCcher-Physik-Edition/dp/3519032368

Comment: What book? Can you add a link to it?

Comment: Perhaps tritium beta decay is not well understood until today [Mainz and Troitsk experiments 2005 reports in english](http://www.physik.uni-mainz.de/exakt/neutrino/en_experiment.html).

Comment: Depending on their sign conventions, the square of the four-momentum is $-m^2$. Are you sure that that table actually means to contain $m^2$ and not $p^2$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the square of the neutrino mass negative?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/578556/why-is-the-square-of-the-neutrino-mass-negative)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In experimental physics, a measure have some  range of uncertainties which is defined by the error bars. Like another example, the dark matter pressure can be positive or negative for warm dark matter models. However, a negative pressure cannot be interpreted in terms of a classical gas and therefore the thermodynamics approach for explaining this would not be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Later in the book they mention that they don't really know how to deal with negative mass squares. But in the range of uncertainties only the positive part is interpreted.