# Negative Neutrino Mass squared

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, weak-interaction

I was reading this recently released paper on [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.06048.pdf) on a new limit on neutrino mass from KATRIN experiment in Germany.

I am puzzled as to how the $m^2$ has negative values. The closest explanation I could find is [this paper on arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0009291)

There was a similar question here : [Negative Mass Square](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222869/negative-mass-square)

Comment: The paper doesn't say that m^2 is negative, it says that their measurement gives a best measured value for m^2 of -1.0 eV with a nominal error of 1.0 eV (simplifying the numbers slightly).    What this means, more or less, is that under the following conditions: 1) the m^2 is actually 0, or at any rate much less than 1.0 eV; 2) everything else relevant is understood about the experiment and the underlying physics 3) the experiment were exactly repeated many times; Then about 16% of the time, you would get an m^2 result that was at least that negative.  i.e. this is probably just chance.

Comment: There are statistical techniques for determining error ranges on bounded fields (example: [Feldman-Cousins](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9711021)) which would be appropriate for this kind of applcation, but they are considerably more complicated than standard techniques and are rarely used for preliminary analyses (a category which includes this early result).

Comment: Do you understand that for a null measurement you get a best fit of negative mass-squared *half the time*?

Comment: Yes, makes sense to me now, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the square of the neutrino mass negative?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/578556/why-is-the-square-of-the-neutrino-mass-negative)

Comment: yes it does. Thank you